# smooth scroll only works for buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this code which allows the page to scroll smoothly when clicking an anchor link:

```
$(function() {
   $('input.anchor-button').click(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      var hash = $(this).parent('form').attr('action');
      var target = $(hash);
      target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + hash.slice(1) +']');
      if (target.length) {
         $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: target.offset().top
         }, 1000);
      }
   });
});
```

```html
<form id = "form_createaccount_button_orange" action="#createfaculty">
   <input type="submit" class="anchor-button" value="  create faculty account  " />
</form>
```

However it will only work for input buttons. I tried `<a href=#createfaculty...` it jumps me to the anchor but the smooth scroll didn't work. Is there anyway to convert perhaps to modify the javascript that it would also work for the `a href` link?

Comment: Your selector is `input.anchor-button`. You'll need to change that for the logic to work on an `<a>` element

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan, so you mean instead of `$('input.anchor-button')` I'd write `$('a')` ?